# Does Fire Bolt require that you can see the creature in order to target it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, targeting, invisibility

Fire Bolt makes no mention of seeing the creature in order to target it in the spell text . Fire Bolt says "creature or object within range". Ray of Frost has very similar language - no mention of seeing the creature. Magic Missile does mention "hits a creature of your choice that you can see within range". This became an issue when fighting invisible stalkers. My GM's argument was that in the core rues for spells it mentions you must be able to see it in order to target it. (I could find no mention of that either). At the time, it was in melee with other players so its general location was known.

Comment: Thank you - this answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

#### You may attempt to attack the target.

Since *fire bolt* calls for an attack<sup>1</sup>, you follow the rules for “Unseen Attackers and Targets” when trying to hit an unseen target:

> When you attack a target that you can't see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you're guessing the target's location or you're targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn't in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target's location correctly.

When attempting to hit an invisible creature with *fire bolt*, you have disadvantage on the attack roll, and you choose a location to sling your fire bolt. The DM will tell you if you hit or miss the target.

The DM may be misremembering the “Clear path to the Target” rule:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

If the reason you cannot see the target is that it is behind total cover, then you cannot target it, *but invisibility is not cover*, so invisibility will not prevent you from trying to hit the target with *fire bolt*.

---

<sup>1 The introduction to the “Making an Attack” section explicitly points out that spells that make an attack roll follow the general rules for attacks: “ Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, *or making an attack roll as part of a spell*, an attack has a simple structure.”</sup>

Comment: I would only note that the DM might be misremembering the rule that requires a *clear path* to the target as requiring you to be able to see the target.